# Approximately time of updating 10 milions row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to update table with more than 10s millions of rows (production). At the beginning there will be added 3 news columns `col1, col2, col3`. These 3 news columns are going to have default value based on other columns `prev_col1, prev_col2, prev_col3`. Old and new columns are `var char` column with max length of 10, some of them may be null. What is the approximate time, i am asking, because i have never updated that many rows at one time.

Should i use simple update:

```
UPDATE table_name SET col1=prev_col1, col2=prev_col2, col3=prev_col3;
```

Or is any other efficient way for updating large amount of rows?

Comment: Are you trying to execute Update the new table and based on the columns values of another table? Or do you have some data in CSV or other format and want to execute it?

Comment: On the columns from the same table

Comment: That depends on the hardware you are using

Answer (score 4):

Efficient ways to update would be the use of [MySQL Join-Buffer-Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html) for updating large rows.
e.g.

```
SET join_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 42;
UPDATE table1 a JOIN table2 b 
ON a.field1 = b.field1 
SET 
a.field2 = b.field2,
a.field3 = b.field3,
a.field4 = b.field4;

mysql> SET GLOBAL join_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 42;
```

May be this can be of some help:- [update-10-million-rows-in-mysql-single-table-as-fast-as-possible](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119621/how-to-update-10-million-rows-in-mysql-single-table-as-fast-as-possible)

Comment: It is curious that this is so upvoted.  I see no indication in the question that there are two tables.  I understand the question as referring to columns *in the same table*, so setting `join_buffer_size` would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a transaction to "test" run your query. But please don't run it directly on production, always work in a cloned version until you're 100% sure what you're doing.

```
START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE table_name SET col1 = prev_col1, col2 = prev_col2, col3 = prev_col3;
ROLLBACK;
```

This will run the query, but instead of committing it will rollback. Will tell you errors and the time in either the console or GUI you use.

Answer (score 1):

The execution time cannot be calculated in general. It depends on the way your server has stored the data (heap, tree ...) as well as the read/write-Speed of your hard-drive or solid state drive.

My professor at the university once said that you can find those informations at the SQL-Server-Activity-Monitor. We never tried it out but im pretty sure you can find some tutorials how to work with it.

Or you just try the Method from @Jelle. Thats a pretty safe way. Altough I recommend doing this over night or at a time the server isnt used that intense.

And another information - you should not care about the performance of your sql request - the ms sql server has a pretty decent optimization build in.